# Error building an association with two foreign keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have a User and Recommendation model. User has several account types: student, admin, recommender, etc. Student users can assign recommenders to submit a recommendation. I am not using Rolify so

I currently have:

```
class Recommendation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :assigner, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "user_id"
  belongs_to :writer,   class_name: "User", foreign_key: "writer_id"
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :recommendations_via_assigning, class_name: "Recommendation", foreign_key: :assigner_id
  has_many :recommendations_via_writing,   class_name: "Recommendation", foreign_key: :writer_id
end

class CreateRecommendations < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :recommendations do |t|
      t.integer :writer_id, foreign_key: true
      t.integer :assigner_id, foreign_key: true
      t.text    :text

      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :recommendations, :writer_id
    add_index :recommendations, :assigner_id
  end
end
```

Controller

```
 def new
   @recommendation = current_user.recommendations_via_assigning.build
 end

 def create
   @recommendation = current_user.recommendations_via_assigning.build(recommendation_request_params)
   if @recommendation.save
     @recommendation.send_invitation_email
     flash[:info] = "An email with submission instructions has been sent to the recommender you have invited."
     redirect_to user_url
   else
     render 'new'
   end
 end

 private
    def recommendation_request_params
     params.require(:recommendation).permit(:assigner_id, :first_name, :last_name, :email, :relationship)
   end

   def recommendation_content_params
     params.require(:recommendation).permit(:writer_id, :first_name, :last_name, :email, :text)
   end
```

I am unable to save a recommendation as it requires the writer_id, which won't be known when recommendation#create is submitted. What needs to happen is an email is issued to the provided email address inviting the teacher to create an account and when that account is registered, the recommendation by id with the writer_id of the teacher account.

How do I modify the existing code so I can pass recommendation#create without a writer_id?

Answer (score 2):

Start by declaring the foreign keys correctly:

```
class CreateRecommendations < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :recommendations do |t|
      t.belongs_to :writer, foreign_key: { to_table: :users }
      t.belongs_to :assigner, foreign_key: { to_table: :users }

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

You need to manually specify the referenced table for the foreign key constraint when it cannot derived from the name of the column.

You also need to set the association as optional to remove the validation:

```
class Recommendation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :assigner, class_name: "User", 
                        foreign_key: "user_id"
  belongs_to :writer,   class_name: "User", 
                        foreign_key: "writer_id",
                        optional: true
end
```

Answer (score 1):

[Read here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to)

You need to make the `belongs_to` association optional:

```
belongs_to :writer, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "writer_id", optional: true
```